# columns selected from listbox directly and through search box needs to be saved

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, listbox, pysimplegui, search-box

In the PySimpleGUI screen along with other elements, I have an Input-text(Search box) and ListBox of column values. Facing an issue while I'm trying to add search functionality for List-Box.
I just started experimenting with PySimpleGUI, Any help would be great :-)

**Expected Output:** *Should be able to pull the selected values through search box on list box and which were selected from Listbox*

Below is the code which I have tried :

```
form = sg.FlexForm('File split script')

layout = [
            [sg.Text('Please upload file & enter the remaining details and click "submit" button to execute the script')],
            [sg.Text('Input File', size=(10, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='left')],
            [sg.InputText('Please upload either the CSV/XLSX input file'), sg.FileBrowse(key="-Input_Values-")],
            [sg.Text('Output File', size=(10, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='left')],
            [sg.InputText('Please choose the output folder'), sg.FolderBrowse(key="-Output_Values-")],
            [sg.Text('No of records per file'), sg.InputText(key = '-no_of_records-'), sg.Text('in multiples of 1000')],
            [sg.Text(' ',size=(5, 1))],
            [sg.InputText('',key = '-Search_Box-', enable_events=True),sg.Button('Merge_Search_Fields_And_Listbox_Selected_Fields')],
            [sg.Text('Select the Required columns')],
            [sg.Listbox(values = (),select_mode= 'multiple', size=(30, 30), key='-ListBox-', enable_events=True),  sg.Button("Populate Columns"), sg.Text('Double click the button',font=('Arial', 13, 'bold')) ],
            [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
         ]

window = form.Layout(layout)
event, values = window.read()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    file_path = values[0]

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
        break

    if event == 'Submit':
        break

    if event == 'Populate Columns':
        #extracts columns from selected input file - stores in 
        #column_names list and populates in ListBox

        column_names = list(df_full_content.columns)
        window.Element('-ListBox-').update(values= column_names)

    # My issue is with handling search box functionality
    if event == '-Search_Box-':
        text = values['-Search_Box-']
        if text in column_names:
            search_set.add(text)

        window.Element('-ListBox-').update(values=search_set)
```

[UI_Screenshot of above-mentioned code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQoUg.png)

Comment: Try to reduce your code to only about your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Jason,  I have reduced the code a little. I kept the layout to understand UI

Answer (score 0):

Two ways here to select columns

- Mode 1: Click item in Listbox element diretly
- Mode 2: Input column name in Input element with enter key

You cannot work in Mode 1, then to Mode 2, then Mode 1 for following code.
To back to Mode 1 from Mode 2, you can click `Reset` Button.

Of course, you can set any rule for it by your programming code, but not for following code for it is not the question in this issue.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

items = [f'Item {i}' for i in range(10)]

search = set()
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Sepcified Column')],
    [sg.Input(size=10, key='SEARCH')],
    [sg.Listbox(items, size=(8, 5), select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_MULTIPLE, key='LISTBOX')],
    [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Reset'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['SEARCH'].bind("<Return>", "+RETURN")
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == 'SEARCH+RETURN':
        item  = values['SEARCH']
        print(item)
        if item in items:
            search.add(item)
            data = sorted(list(search))
            index = data.index(item)
            window['LISTBOX'].update(values=data, set_to_index=[i for i in range(len(data))], scroll_to_index=index)
            window['SEARCH'].update('')

    elif event == 'Reset':
        search = set()
        window['LISTBOX'].update(values=items)

    elif event == 'Submit':
        selected = values['LISTBOX']
        print(selected)

window.close()
```

```py
['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
```

Comment: User uploads input file, As soon as the user uploads - The script extracts the columns from the input file and populates in the list box, Upon that users can select the columns of their choice to write them to another file. Incase if file has a large number of columns it would be difficult to select them so I would like to add search functionality to the list box - This where I'm struggling and need you help

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Jason, Actually I trying to select columns in both ways  1) Click them directly in the list box 2) As soon as I type in the search box columns should reflect in Listbox in real-time from there user can select. In the end, selected values through both the ways should retain. Although solution did not gave the expected solution however I learnt a lot and got a clue to take it forward Thank you Jason,  I would like to upvote your answer but due to lack of reputation It is not registering my UPVOTE.